# How to access variables inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have been trying to solve this all of yesterday and today but cannot figure it out. I have the following returned in a variable called

```
var myRequest = req.body
console.log(myRequest)
```

Produces the following:

```
{
    "methodcall": {
        "methodname": ["userLogin"],
        "params": [{
            "param": [{
                "value": [{
                    "string": ["test1"]
                }]
            }, {
                "value": [{
                    "string": ["password"]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Now, I need to access the params key, and access the first param value so that whatever is returned in the first param value string is stored as username in a variable, and whatever is returned in param value string (the second one), is stored as a password.

So the final effect something like this:

```
var username = myRequest.methodcall.params.param...first value string
var password = myRequest.methodcall.params.param...second value string
```

However, I am really struggling to understand how to do this. Im guessing forEach loops would come in this, however I do not have experience with them so would appreciate some tips.

Also, when I try doing `myRequest.methodcall`, I keep getting undefined returned.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the liberty to change the object structure?

Comment: No... but I am trying to learn coding so I guess as silly as the questions seems the answers will help me

Comment: `myRequest.methodcall.params[0].param[0].value[0].string[0]` and `myRequest.methodcall.params[0].param[1].value[0].string[0]` will allow you to access it directly. Whenever you see the square brackets, this denotes an array, hence why you have to access it like an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your value is in JSON, parse it first and then you should presumably be able to get its values:

```
var myRequest = JSON.parse(req.body);

var userName = myRequest.methodcall.params[0].param[0].value[0].string[0];
var password = myRequest.methodcall.params[0].param[1].value[0].string[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted is JSON. you need to set it up like:

```
var myRequest = JSON.parse(req.body)
```

this will allow you to access the it like a normal js object.

Comment: ahh I see. But then how would I ensure the first value is stored as username and the second as password?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` to access keys in object and `[]` to access index in array.

This code should work:

`var username = myRequest.methodcall.params[0].param[0].value[0].string[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a loop at get the values `test1`,`password`, and so on. You can use a loop and access the `param` array:

```
var params = myRequest.methodcall.params[0].param;

params.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.value[0].string[0]);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pkgoxcz2/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//var myRequest = JSON.parse(req.body) // if JSON

var myRequest = {
  "methodcall": {
    "methodname": ["userLogin"],
    "params": [{
      "param": [{
        "value": [{
          "string": ["test1"]
        }]
      }, {
        "value": [{
          "string": ["password"]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
};

var params = myRequest.methodcall.params;
var uname, pwd;
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
  console.log("uname is " + params[i].param[0].value[0].string);
  console.log("pwd is " + params[i].param[1].value[0].string)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your response structure will be same then no need to go for loop or something, just directly access the username and password from response.
try this.

```
var username = myRequest.methodcall.params[0].param[0].value[0].string[0];
var password = myRequest.methodcall.params[0].param[1].value[0].string[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you debug your code?
I mean these code:

```
var username = myRequest.methodcall.params.param[0];
var password = myRequest.methodcall.params.param[1];
```